Indirect not returning values as expected in formula searching for date ranges
I was using the base formula from this post: Excel - Number of occurrences of specific day and month between two dates?
I am reaching out for help now, as I am trying to accomplish the same purpose as the OP there: Identify the number of specific days within a given date range, even over the course of years.
But when I duplicate the solution from the post above, the Indirect function is not working properly (as best I can tell). Depending on what I have tried so far with "'" or not, when I "F9" solve for the Indirect section, I either get this when I enter your formula exactly as is:
Original equation: =SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($H$45&":"&$H$46)),"ddmmm")=H$48&$I48)+0)
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW({0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
.... Lots of lines of the same thing here.... .... 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0});"ddmmm")=H$48&$I48)+0)
OR I get: =SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW({44835;45383});"ddmmm")=H$48&$I48)+0) when I have entered: =SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("$H$45:$H$46"));"ddmmm")=H$48&$I48)+0)
Can anyone share a hint as to what it is that is wrong with my indirect?

The above formula works for me, please refer screenshot below:


• Formula used in cell B5
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(B1&":"&B2)),"ddmmm")=B4&C4)+0)


• But, instead of using INDIRECT() function which is a volatile function - slows down the working efficiency of Excel as well keeps recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook therefore, you could try using one of the following as well:
=SUM(N(TEXT(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),"ddmmm")=B4&C4))

or, the above formula is applicable to MS365/Excel 2021 perhaps for older versions could try which needs to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode based on ones Excel Version:
=SUMPRODUCT(N(TEXT(B1+ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,B2-B1+1))-1,"ddmmm")=B4&C4))


Answer posted based on the question: Excel - Number of occurrences of specific day and month between two dates?


Beautiful thank you for the countersuggestion. I like more efficient and most importantly , working... I played around with Indirect for a good half hour trying to fix it. I have some unusual settings on my computer though due to regions and stuff with work. Maybe that's why. Thanks again!

Sounds Good, glad to know you made it work!
